# Printing list of options from a select element in Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, developer-tools

I am trying to pull the list of values from a select element while in Developer Tools console for Chrome (or Firefox), but I'm having trouble with the various answers I've seen in other places are a few years old and don't seem to work for me.

Take the following as an example:

```
<select id="states">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
</select>
```

My selector on the console would be:

```
$$('#states > option').values
```

Values returns an ArrayIterator.  But I'm not sure what to do with that.

What I would like to have returned are the value of each option and the text of each option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unsure of how you want your data, you could push them to an array, or an object? Here's an example of getting an array of arrays, each sub array containing [val,text]:

```
var states = [];
$('#states option').each(function(){
    states.push([$(this).val(),$(this).text() ]);
});
console.log(states);
```

EDIT: Try this, doesn't use jQuery, will just log the info out for you, but you could push it to an empty array like above if you wish.

```
var states = $$('#states > option');
for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    console.log(states[i].value, states[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: When I try that, I get: `Uncaught TypeError: $$(...).each is not a function(…)`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Whatever version comes with Chrome version 49.0.2623.112.  Perhaps I shouldn't have specified JQuery, specifically, but that I'm in Chrome's Dev Tools console.

Comment: Check out my edited post above, jQuery doesn't come with chrome, you're just using Chrome's selector API.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Of course, using the map() function on states also works (as I found out).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
const statesEl = document.getElementById('states');
const options = statesEl.getElementsByTagName('option');

const optionValues = Array.prototype.map.call(options, function(optionEl) {
  return {
    value: optionEl.getAttribute('value'),
    text: optionEl.textContent
  };
});
```

Then you can use `optionValues` array

```js
    const statesEl = document.getElementById('states');
    const options = statesEl.getElementsByTagName('option');

    const optionValues = Array.prototype.map.call(options, function(optionEl) {
      return {
        value: optionEl.getAttribute('value'),
        text: optionEl.textContent
      };
    });
    
    console.log(optionValues);
```

```html
<select id="states">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you are not using es6 you can just use `var` instead for `const` in your code and it should work all the same :-)

Comment: this is the cleanest solution to me: straight JS, no need for jquery. This works straight in the chrome console to extract dropdown values. Nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values like this:

```
 var states = $('#states > option');
 states.each(function(){ 
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log(this.text);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just this:

```
$('#states > option').each(function (){ 
    console.log(this.value, this.text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your assistance. Every answer got me close to my solution. For some reason "each" was not working for me, but "map" did.

Here's my answer:

```
var states = $$('#states option')
states.map(function(state) {
  console.log(state.value, state.text);
});
```